# N3 notation to RDF/XML

Tags: rdf, rdfs, n3

I have to sample N3 and I need to convert it to the corresponds RDF/XML format please , any help ?

```
 crop:AttributeValue a rdfs:Class . 
 crop:SomeValue a rdfs:Class; rdfs:subClassOf crops:AttributeValue .

 crop:SomeValue/7 a crops:SomeValue .

 crop:SomeValue a rdf:Property ; rdfs:range crops:SomeValue .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specifiy a bit more info, e.g. like this

```
@prefix crop: <http://example.org/foo#> .
@prefix crops: <http://example.org/foo#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/> .

crop:AttributeValue a rdfs:Class . crop:SomeValue a rdfs:Class; rdfs:subClassOf crops:AttributeValue .

<http://example.org/foo#SomeValue/7> a crops:SomeValue .

crop:SomeValue a rdf:Property ; rdfs:range crops:SomeValue .
```

Replace the namespaces for crop and crops with the correct ones.

This would be the following in RDF/XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:crops="http://example.org/foo#">
    <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/foo#SomeValue">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/foo#AttributeValue" />
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Property" />
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://example.org/foo#SomeValue" />
    </rdfs:Class>
    <crops:SomeValue rdf:about="http://example.org/foo#SomeValue/7" />
</rdf:RDF>
```

Here is an online tool for the conversion : http://www.rdfabout.com/demo/validator/

Comment: thanks for your post , you just come to rescue :)
just one question please , I have to RDF validator, one form Jena and the other is the w3c validator:
when I tried to validate the following RDF , it works fine on the Jena validator , but problems appear in the W3C validator , here is the RDF :

{<rdf:Property rdf:about="http://example.org/crops/SomeValue">
   <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://example.org/crops/Attribute/Value" />
  </rdf:Property>}
the error is :
Error: {E201} rdf:about not allowed as attribute 
do you have any idea please about what is going ?

Comment: You need to provide the rdf:RDF wrapper element, all the XML namespace declarations and about and resource need to refer to proper URIs, then the validator doesn't complain : `<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/">
  <rdf:Property rdf:about="http://example.org/crops/SomeValue">
     <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://example.org/crops/Attribute/Value" />     </rdf:Property>
</rdf:RDF>`

Answer (score 2):

You should check first if you have a valid n3 representation of your data. For example you use a prefix named `crop` and a prefix named `crops`. Assuming that these are correct, you also need to define your prefixes (crop, crops, rdf, rdfs). A valid example would be:

```
@prefix crop: <http://crop.org> .
@prefix crops: <http://crops.org> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

crop:AttributeValue a rdfs:Class . crop:SomeValue a rdfs:Class; rdfs:subClassOf crops:AttributeValue .
crop:SomeValue a crops:SomeValue .
crop:SomeValue a rdf:Property ; rdfs:range crops:SomeValue .
```

For a validation and conversion you might than check out [RDF About](http://www.rdfabout.com/demo/validator/) Validator. Alternatively you can use [this](http://www.mindswap.org/2002/rdfconvert/) tool as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Jena](https://jena.apache.org/), there is a command-line tool [rdfcat](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html) which can convert files between RDF/XML, N-triples and Turtle formats.